# Проблема с установкой Python

Tags: python, pycharm

При попытке добавить интерпретатор в Pycharm происходит ошибка
[image: ошибка в Pycharm]

Также не открывается не сам интерпретатор Python 3.8, ни IDLE (Python 3.8).

Что делать?

Comment: Полагаю, не хватает модуля. Возможно поможет:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087049/fatal-python-error-initfsencoding-unable-to-load-the-file-system-codec

Answer (score 1):

Такая пробема случается, если значение *PYTHONHOME*/*PYTHONPATH* неверное/не установлено.

Данные переменные должны указывать на директорию, в которую установлен Python (в вашем случае - *C:\Program Files\Python38*).

Алгоритм создания/задания значения в Windows 10 (взято отсюда https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml)

1. В строке "Поиск" выполните поиск: Система (Панель управления)
2. Нажмите на ссылку Дополнительные параметры системы.
3. Нажмите Переменные среды. В разделе Переменные среды выберите переменную среды PYTHONHOME. Нажмите Изменить. Если переменной PYTHONHOME не существует, нажмите Создать.
4. В окне Изменение системной переменной (или Новая системная переменная) укажите значение переменной среды PYTHONHOME. Нажмите ОК. Закройте остальные открытые окна, нажимая ОК.

Comment: Не в этом дело, я уже пробовал в Pycharm несколько раз менять путь, и проблема остаётся. Даже в командой строке при наборе python такая же ошибка происходит. Следовательно ошибка в установке Python происходит, и да, я уже несколько раз переустанавливал Python но ошибка каждый раз после установки.

Comment: @SToCKChannel речь не о Pycharm, а о системный переменных Windows. Тут пример, как их задавать: https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml

Comment: Спасибо большое! Настроил переменные и всё заработало!